# Override method of object like in JavaScript

Tags: java, overriding

In JavaScript I can write:

```
myobject.doSomething = function() {
    // stuff..
}
```

So how do I use this @Override-thing of Java to achieve the same?

Comment: Can you be please more specific about your issue. And please don't ask us convert code from one language to another. We don't do it.

Comment: You can't do that in Java. It's not a dynamic language like JavaScript.

Comment: Java's OO is not prototype-based, unlike that of Javascript.  So you cannot do this.

Comment: so how does this @Override-thing work?

Comment: `@Override` doesn't *do* anything.  It's simply an *annotation*, that [allows the compiler to perform further sanity checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why).

Comment: @partofweb: you're basically asking us to explain you the principle of inheritance and polymorphism in Java. Read a good book or tutorial. This is a too broad question for SO. My advice: try to forget what you know about JS when learning Java. They're completely diferent languages, with completely different approaches.

Comment: oh. okay. so now that I know that it is not possible in the way I need it, should I delete the question?

Comment: Don't delete it, it could serve for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot override a method of a single `object` in `Java` because `Java` is not a functional language. You can, however, override the method in a subclass of the `class` declaring your method.

Declaring an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
new MyClass() {
    @Override void myMethod() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

**Main.java**

```
private class SuperClass
{
    public void myMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Test!");
    }
}

private class ChildClass extends SuperClass
{
    @Override
    public void myMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("Testtest!");
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SuperClass superInstance = new SuperClass();
        ChildClass childInstance = new ChildClass();

        superInstance.myMethod();
        childInstance.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this when the object is being created using an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html); basically you create a subclass for the one object only. Example:

```
Label label = new Label() {
    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        super.setText(text);
        System.out.println("Text has been set to " + text);
    }
};

label.setText("Test");
```